# Finding XML elements using xpath and conditions

Tags: xml, xpath

I have an XML document for which I need to extract some text, and I'm trying to define an xpath expression that would find that element based on the value of a ancestor/sibling node.

Easier with an example... In the XML below, for each `<feature>` node, I want to get the value of the `<content>` elements only if the textual value of the `<name>` element is "positive":

```
<root>
    <feature id="1c4">
        <head>
            <name>positive</name>
        </head>
        <values>
            <value id="qwqwq">
                <content>Content-yes</content>
            </value>
        </values>

    </feature>
    <feature id="1c5">
        <head>
            <name>negative</name>
        </head>
        <values>
            <value id="wtrwt">
                <content>Target-no</content>
            </value>
        </values>
    </feature>
</root>
```

I can easily find all the elements (including the ones I don't want) with this: `//root/feature/values/value/content`

And I can find the `<name>` elements if the content value is "positive": `//root/feature/head/name[text() = "positive"]`

But how can I combine both to find the values of `//root/feature/values/value/content` ONLY when `//root/feature/head/name[text() = "positive"]` is true?

I tried to combine the expressions at the `<feature>` node level, but that doesn't seem to be a valid xpath expression: `//root/feature[/head/name[text() = "positive" and /values/value/content]`

Thanks in advance for the help!

F

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this...

```xml
/root/feature[head/name='positive']/values/value/content
```

Comment: Hello @Daniel Haley,

That works perfectly for what I need to do, thank you so much and have a great day!

F